# How to get started brewing sake

Tags: equipment, sake

I have a packet of koji spores and these instructions: http://www.tibbs-vision.com/sake/instrct.html

The instructions call for a 2.6 gal fermenting vessel.  Since I have a 7.9 gal bucket, I am considering brewing a double or triple batch.

I've been brewing mead, cider and all-grain beer, and have typical equipment for it (carboys, buckets, hydrometers, bottling equipment, sanitizers, etc.)  How suitable it for sake?

Does anyone have any advice, tips or pitfalls to avoid?

Answer (score 1):

All the info you need is at:

http://homebrewsake.com/home/recipe/.

Another outstanding site for sake brewing is

http://www.taylor-madeak.org/index.php

Both sites have recipes and step by step procedures for commercial quality sake.

Will

Answer (score 0):

You’re basically all set. However, Sake is very temperature sensitive throughout the process and the rice needs to be steamed.

Fred Eckhardt
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Eckhardt

Fred Eckhardt’s book
[http://www.amazon.com/Sake-USA-complete-breweries-homebrewed/dp/0960630287](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0960630287)

Comment: just noticed the date on the question. How’d things go?